# NSTimeInterval as a countdown timer, applying it as a seperate reusable class

Tags: ios, swift

EDIT: I'm an idiot. I was trying to put the variable into `NSTimer()` and not `NSTimeInterval` for whatever silly reason. I guess my question is how can I wrap this all up in a separate class?

Ideally, I'd like all this wrapped up in a separate class (`CountdownTimer`), so I can create new instance of a timer but still retain all the functionality that `NSTimer` includes such as the ability to check `timer.isValid`. Psuedocode would look something like:

```
var timer = CountdownTimer(countDownFrom: 300) 
timer.start()
timer.isValid()
```

My `UIViewController` class (not in `viewDidLoad`):

```
var totalCountDownTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(480.0)

var startTime = NSDate()

var timer = NSTimer()
var isRunning = false

func updateTime() {
    var elapsedTime : NSTimeInterval  = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)
    var remainingTime : NSTimeInterval = totalCountDownTimeInterval - elapsedTime

    if remainingTime <= 0.0 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    let minutes = UInt8(remainingTime / 60.0)
    remainingTime = remainingTime - (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    let seconds = UInt8(remainingTime)
    println("The time is \(minutes) and \(seconds)")

}


@IBOutlet weak var TimerCount: UILabel!


@IBAction func StartButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !timer.valid {
        startTime = NSDate()
        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.10, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}


@IBAction func StopButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
}

@IBAction func ResetButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
    TimerCount.text = "00:00"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are using totalCountDownTimeInterval in your method, which you can set to whatever you want. How would you like to pass it in?

Comment: If I do something like var selectedTime = 400 and then try to pass that into NSTimeInterval(selectedTime) it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. The goal is to allow a user to select their own time to countdown from.

Comment: How about if you do "var selectedTime = 400.0" which would make it a double. That worked for me. you need to show where in your code you're trying to do this.

Comment: Its a in ViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're actually passing in a double. I like to explicitly state the type of my variables when I declare them; it helps to avoid problems just like this.

You're most likely declaring `doubleValue` like this:

```
let doubleValue = 480
```

instead of like this:

```
let doubleValue = 480.0
```

or like this:

```
let doubleValue: Double = 480
```

If you've declared your variable correctly, this *should* work:

```
let timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(doubleValue)
```

If you are going to let the compiler infer the variable's type, just make sure that whatever's on the right side of your assignment operator evaluates to the type you're looking for. `480` evaluates to `Int(480)` while `480.0` evaluates to `Double(480)`.

---

**EDIT**: Here's the answer to your second question: *How can I wrap this [timer functionality] up in a separate class?*

It's actually really simple. Assuming that all you want to do with the class is to be able to start it and check if it's still valid, here's how I would go about doing this:

```
class CountdownTimer
{
    var time: NSTimeInterval

    private var startTime: NSDate?

    init(countDownFrom timeInSeconds: Int)
    {
        time = NSTimeInterval(timeInSeconds)
    }

    func start()
    {
        startTime = NSDate()
    }

    func isValid() -> Bool
    {
        if (startTime != nil)
        {
            let timePassed: NSTimeInterval = -(startTime!.timeIntervalSinceNow)

            return timePassed < time
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Now, be warned, I barely tested this. Playground isn't complaining and from the looks of it, this should work. Now, just use the class like so:

```
var myCountdownTimer = CountdownTimer(countDownFrom: 300)

// and then whenever we want to start the countdown:

myCountdownTimer.start()

// and then whenever we want to check if the clock's still "ticking", so to speak:

myCountdownTimer.isValid()

// and if we want to restart the timer:

myCountdownTimer.time = NSTimeInterval(900) // we can change the time if we want
myCountdownTimer.start()
```

Essentially, all a CountdownTimer object does is save the exact time `start()` is called to a variable called `startTime`. Note that `NSDate()` by default is set to the time-and-date it's created. Then `isValid()` simply checks to see if the `timePassed` is less than whatever `time` the timer was set to count down from; if it is, then it returns `true`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. If `doubleValue` is indeed an instantiated property of type `Double` somewhere in your class' immediate scope, then `let timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(doubleValue)` should work anywhere in your entire class. Be sure to double-check the line where you're declaring the `Double` and the line where you're passing it into the `NSTimeInterval` init function. I guarantee your error lies on one of those two lines.

Comment: Oh, alright. Haha, that was a silly mistake, but it's okay, I've made worse mistakes than that. I'm not sure if it's against the rules to change your question entirely mid-discussion, but I'll attempt to answer it anyway. (;

Comment: This looks good, but I'll want to add the functionality to output time remaining.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code on playground of Xcode 6.1, And It worked fine.
That's strange...

```
let someValue: Double = 60.0
var timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(someValue)
println(timeInterval)
```